# Remotely Debug Swift on Linux with Xcode

Tags: swift, linux, xcode, bluetooth

I'd like to remotely dev/run/debug a Swift Bluetooth program using Xcode on a Mac host to a remote (SBC) ASUS Tinkerboard S with Debian OS.

After much effort in searching and piecing together random blogs, the following portion is working:

- Installed Swift on Debian (Swift version 4.2.1 (swift-4.2.1-RELEASE))
- In Debian, can build with Swift and run via terminal using simple Swift code.
- Used an online example to setup Xcode project with ability to remotely build, rsync (Swish), and step thru code remotely via Xcode. https://swiftreviewer.com/2018/12/25/compile-swift-for-raspberry-pi-by-xcode/

When I check the version of Swift:

```
$ swift -v
Swift version 4.2.1 (swift-4.2.1-RELEASE)
Target: armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
/usr/bin/lldb "--repl=-disable-objc-interop -color-diagnostics"
error: failed to stop process at REPL breakpoint
```

What isn't working:

1. I need Bluetooth support so added the following to Package.swift (from https://github.com/PureSwift: BluetoothLinux, GATT, SwiftFoundation.
2. After editing Package.swift, I regenerate the `.xcodeproj` by calling `swift package generate-xcodeproj`.
3. A warning shows: warning: `PackageDescription API v3 is deprecated and will be removed in the future; used by package(s): SwiftFoundation, CJSONC, CStatfs`
4. Then since the re-gen process wipes out the remote build target, added it back.
5. Try to build and it errors out with the below message. I checked and the `x86_64-linux-gnu` folder and its missing. I've installed the dependencies that I know of... and I thought it should be using `armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` instead.

```
-----------------------------
Configuration:
-----------------------------
Username: linaro
Hostname: tinkerboard.local
Destination: ~/Swish/swift_program
-----------------------------
  Start syncing project to linaro@tinkerboard.local:~/Swish/swift_program
sending incremental file list
./
Package.swift

            993 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00  
            993 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=12/16)
  Did sync project to remote machine
⚒  Start building project
bash: /home/linaro/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
warning: PackageDescription API v3 is deprecated and will be removed in the future; used by package(s): SwiftFoundation, CJSONC, CStatfs
Compile Swift Module 'SwiftFoundation' (39 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Bluetooth' (430 sources)
/home/linaro/Swish/swift_program/.build/checkouts/CStatfs.git--2064549412/module.modulemap:2:12: error: header '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/vfs.h' not found
    header "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/vfs.h"
           ^
/home/linaro/Swish/swift_program/.build/checkouts/SwiftFoundation--958978667/Sources/SwiftFoundation/FileDescriptor.swift:13:12: error: could not build C module 'CStatfs'
    import CStatfs
           ^
/home/linaro/Swish/swift_program/.build/checkouts/CStatfs.git--2064549412/module.modulemap:2:12: error: header '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/vfs.h' not found
    header "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/vfs.h"
           ^
/home/linaro/Swish/swift_program/.build/checkouts/SwiftFoundation--958978667/Sources/SwiftFoundation/FileDescriptor.swift:13:12: error: could not build C module 'CStatfs'
    import CStatfs
           ^
/home/linaro/Swish/swift_program/.build/checkouts/CStatfs.git--2064549412/module.modulemap:2:12: error: header '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/vfs.h' not found
    header "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/vfs.h"
           ^
/home/linaro/Swish/swift_program/.build/checkouts/SwiftFoundation--958978667/Sources/SwiftFoundation/FileDescriptor.swift:13:12: error: could not build C module 'CStatfs'
    import CStatfs
           ^
/home/linaro/Swish/swift_program/.build/checkouts/CStatfs.git--2064549412/module.modulemap:2:12: error: header '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/vfs.h' not found
    header "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/vfs.h"
           ^
/home/linaro/Swish/swift_program/.build/checkouts/SwiftFoundation--958978667/Sources/SwiftFoundation/FileDescriptor.swift:13:12: error: could not build C module 'CStatfs'
    import CStatfs
           ^
error: terminated(1): /usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /home/linaro/Swish/swift_program/.build/debug.yaml main output:
```

My Package.swift file:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.2
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "swift_program",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/PureSwift/BluetoothLinux.git", .branch("master")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/PureSwift/GATT", .branch("master")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/PureSwift/SwiftFoundation.git", .branch("master"))
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "swift_program",
            dependencies: ["BluetoothLinux", "GATT", "SwiftFoundation"])
    ]
)
```

Any help/suggestions are appreciated.